# Lenovo NAS ix2-NG setup copy firmware

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I have a used Lenovo NAS ix2-NG without disk when I connected it to PC I was not able to access it through LAN cable, I came to know that its firmware/OS was on the installed HDD.  To setup this drive i have to copy its firmware/OS to new HDD that I'm going to install.  I was not able to find any useful information or walkthrough on the internet.

I'm using windows 10 OS to setup this drive, please if anyone can help, how can i copy its firmware/OS to get start on this.

On some forums I read may be it uses Linux OS? i setup VM on my windows computer with Ubuntu that may help or i also have Raspberry Pi I can get help to update firmware on NAS drive.

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that I also tried to access through router.

Edit 2: some links regarding the issue

- https://www.myhacklog.com/restore-an-iomega-lenovo-storcenter-ix2-ng/
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Iomega-Desktop-Network-Storage/Lenovo-Iomega-ix2-ng-restore-firmware/m-p/4269281
- http://download.lenovo.com/lenovoemc/eu/en/app/cust_alp/p/1031%2c1149.html
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Enterprise-Storage/ix2-ng-Firmware-restore/m-p/5009944
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Network-Storage/IX2-ng-firmware/m-p/4208698

Comment: Have you tried to follow instructions from the 1st link?

Comment: Yes, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't connect it directly to a PC. Connect it to your router, so that the NAS will get an IP address from router's DHCP server. Connecting directly to a PC is possible, but I'd suggest starting with the easiest setup possible to avoid unnecessary difficulties. Once you have it running you can try alternative setups.

NASes typically have some kind of bootloader that is able to install OS on the disk. Just pop in a new disk and try to find the NAS on your network. Enter its IP in the browser and follow instructions on screen.

Consult the [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/701500/Lenovo-Ix2.html) if necessary.

Comment: I also tried connecting through router did not get access, while searching on the internet i came to know, without having firmware in it i can't access it through browser.

Comment: @sairfan Can you link to the resources you've found?

Comment: while working i did not save links, i will try to find those again and update in my question